# How to install dotless on local pc, windows 10

Tags: installation, command-line, dotless

How to install dotless on local pc from command line.

First I install Ruby, then put in console "gem install nu", then "nu install dotless".
The installation tells me for all files: "required"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download and install Ruby 1.9.3
2. In command line put: gem install nu
3. In project folder put: nu install dotless
4. In project folder put: dotless less\style.less css\style.css (this item only one time, when you create a progect; you must keep your .less in folder less and .css in folder css;)
5. In project folder put: dotless less\style.less --watch css\style.css
6. When you finish coding in command line press "Enter" for stop watching